# regex require at least one match

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regular expression that is supposed to find instances of a specific class in a document. This class is noted by a one of two symbols (let us call them X and Y) being in **one or more** of three specific locations in the match.

currently my expression looks like this:

```
'X?(?:expression_one)[XY]?(?:expression_two)Y?(?:optional_end_expression)?'
```

The problem is that this will match a string that fulfills `'expression_oneexpression_two'` without any of the symbols. I would like to know if there is a way to restrict the above expression such that `X` or `Y` must exist in **at least one** of the locations in order to match.

## EXAMPLE

here is the simplest regex example for this kind of problem

```
r = re.compile(r'\$?\d*[\$%]?\d*%?')
```

this will match

- $44
- 44%
- 34$53%
- AND ANY NUMBER

I would like it so that it required those symbols to exist in **at least one** of the specified locations so that it **does not just match any number** in the text

Comment: Can you include some examples of match and non-match?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: try changing `?` into `+`: `'X?(?:expression_one)[XY]+(?:expression_two)Y+(?:optional_end_expression)?'`

Comment: Either use 3 alternatives, or positive look-ahead. However, I do not know what boundaries you have for the look-ahead (`(?=.*[XY])`?) to work.

Comment: I added an example if that helps. It is a much simpler example than my actual project, but it gets the same idea across and is easier to test and recreate

Comment: @stribizhev I will look into that, but the locations are specific in my case. Wouldn't a look ahead not specify that they are in the specific locations?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "locations". Here is [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS6gV2/1) of what I meant.

Comment: Sometimes it's easiest to do these things in two steps.  First find the substrings that match your regex.  Then filter the matches to get only those that contain at least one of the symbols $ or %.

Answer (score 1):

Since your expression is fairly simple, I'd explicitly list each form, using the `|` operator, like so:

```
import re

# Original, from question
# r = re.compile(r'\$?\d*[\$%]?\d*%?')

# New RE. Strategy is to explicitly match each possible form
r = re.compile(r'''
    (?x)                 # Verbose RE
    (\$\d*[\$%]?\d*%?)   # Matches $FOO
    | (\$?\d*[\$%]\d*%?) # Matches FOO$BAR, FOO%BAR
    | (\$?\d*[\$%]?\d*%) # Matches BAR%
''')


# Tests:
assert r.match("$44")
assert r.match("44%")
assert r.match("34$53%")
assert not r.match("1987")
```